# JavaScript switch function for what the URL contains (bookmarklet)

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want to make a bookmarklet that will do something based on what website you are on. How could I detect this and make use of it for a switch function?

It would need to work for all pages inside of the site (like example.com/play and /select, for example). As an additional question, how can you make one case allow 2 things? Can you just use logical or? Would the below be acceptable?

```
switch(var) {
case "a" || "b":
alert("a or b");
break;
case "c":
alert("c");
break;
default:
alert("don't know");
break;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could just get the URL and see on which page you are. Take a look at [How to get the current URL](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_get_url.asp).
You can easily have two cases do the same thing. You just have to write the two cases and put what you want in the second and no break in the first: `case "a": \n case "b": \n alert("a or b"); \n break;` (`\n` is a new line)